# What is the php code for an Elementor header?

Tags: theme-development

I'm building a WP theme demo with OCDI, TGMPA and Elementor. That works fine, except it doesn't show the Elementor header and footer. The .dat file does import them; I have to activate them manually. I don't know how to do that.

It should be something like this function for the menu:

```
    // Assign menus to their locations.
    $primary = get_term_by('name', 'Main', 'nav_menu');
    $social  = get_term_by('name', 'Social', 'nav_menu');

    set_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations', array(
        'menu-1' => $primary->term_id,
        'mobile' => $primary->term_id,
        'social' => $social->term_id,
    ));
```

I don't know php. The header name is 'Header', and its id is 43. How can I do this?

It would help if I know where to find a list with OCDI functions. Do I need to create a function?